# Implementing mib2c template for scalar

Tags: centos7, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am trying to get the mib2c template code to work for a simple scalar, but continue to get `MY-MIB::mibName = No such object available on this agent at this OID` upon a snmpget request no matter what I do.

When generating the mib2c template code I choose the net-snmp -> scalar options. From there I have tried options 1 and 2.
My understanding of the option 2 template is that you shouldn't even have to change any of the code to get it to successfully return a zero value for scalars.
However, the debug messages show that the init_* functions are getting called but the handlers are not getting called at all.

I am wondering if anyone can point me to resources showing a successful implementation example of the mib2c generated code as I am fairly lost at this point.
Thanks!

Comment: try `MY-MIB::mibName.0`

Comment: @TallChuck I have tried that with the same result